# Laravel, как правильно изменить сегмент локали?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, поиск-библиотек, locale

Раньше мой селект с выбором языка выглядел следующим образом:

```
@foreach (config('app.available_locales') as $locale)
    @if ($locale != App::getLocale())
        <a href="{{ route('setLocale', $locale) }}">
             {{$locale}}
        </a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

И, соответственно, роут изменения локали исполнял всю логику - брал текущий урл, менял локаль, сетил ее, и редиректил куда надо.

Мне же надо его изменить так, чтобы урл был сразу готов в селекте. Т.е. если пользователь на `test.com/profile`, в селекте должны быть ссылки `test.com/ru/profile` и `test.com/uk/profile`

Я создала новый сервис, который, по идее, должен возвращать массив с готовыми ссылками, по которому я просто пройдусь в блейде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу додуматься как сгенерировать ссылку, если локаль уже указана. Я использовала `array_shift($segment[1])`, что, как я думала, уберет префикс локали с урла и потом я смогу просто засетить новую `array_unshift($new_locale)`, но не вышло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как ответ был дан @Arendach. Попробую дать другое решение.

Зачем мучаться и изобретать велосипед? Есть готовый, популярный, протестированный пакет: https://packagist.org/packages/mcamara/laravel-localization

Там в документации есть пример простого selecta. Так же пакет умеет определять язык из headers браузера, что направит пользователя сразу на нужную локальа.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Этот пакет буквально меня спас. Весь его функционал я писала сама на протяжении недели. 5 минут - и все работает :)

Answer (score 1):

```php
$uri = trim('/uk/page/lorem-ipsum', '/'); // чистим строку от слешей
$default = 'en'; // локаль по умолчанию
$hide_default = true; // скрывать дефолтную локаль
$locales = ['uk', 'en', 'ru']; // доступные локали

$locales_list = implode('|', $locales); // строка для регулярки uk|ru|en|etc

$pattern = "@^($locales_list)@"; // @^(uk|ru|en|etc)@

$uri = preg_replace($pattern, '', $uri); // /page/lorem-ipsum

foreach ($locales as $locale){
   if (($locale == $default) && $hide_default) {
      echo 'http://example.com' . $uri; // http://examle.com/page/...
   } else {
       echo 'http://examle.com' . '/' . $locale . $uri; // http://examle.com/ru/page/...
   }
}
```

Это скорее псевдокод чем рабочий вариант но надеюсь суть понятна. Удалить у адресной строки локаль при помощи регулярки а дальше просто подставить нужную.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e74c3d2fdeafc6d3ac0d2b1f494b12209d8d551 протестил здесь, код даже рабочий, только свои значения подставить

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :3